# php jquery conditional alert or redirect

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have a script to check validation through mysql db, i use jquery to post and call back a result, if validate success will redirect to another url, else will pop up a reminder alert.

```
function chkValid(){
$.post('check_validate.php', $("#form").serialize(), function(data) {

    // if invalid, pop up alert 
    alert(data);

    // if valid, redirect
    window.location("url");

});
```

could it be done by the scripts above?

Thanks.
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must get what the "check_validate.php" returns to you that was processed in the server side.

your "check_validate.php" must echo a message... for example

```
<?php
//check_validate.php
if($_POST["req"]=="iamnew"){
        echo "welcome";
}
else{
echo "unwelcome";
}
?>
```

and let the Jquery process the echo string of your check_validate.php

```
$.post('check_validate.php',{ req: "iamnew" }, $("#form").serialize(), function(data) {
    if(data=="unwelcome"){
    alert(data);
}
else if(data=="welcome"){
    window.location("url");
}
});
```

Comment: the "data" variable holds what was the response of your "check_validate.php" and so you can use it for your authentication or something you are processing =)

Answer (score 0):

```
function chkValid(){
    $.post('check_validate.php', $("#form").serialize(), function(data) {
        if(data!='valid') {
            // if invalid, pop up alert 
            alert(data);
        }
        else {
            // if valid, redirect
            window.location.href("http://www.example.url");
        }
    });
}
```

make sure you must echo a single string to indicate whether the data is valid or invalid in php code.

```
echo 'valid';
```

or

```
echo 'invalid';
```

in check_validate.php

Answer (score 0):

You can send a flag as response to ajax request .. say   send "1" if success operation and "0" if invalid operation

```
function chkValid(){
 $.post('check_validate.php', $("#form").serialize(), function(data) {

if(datat=="0")  // if invalid, pop up alert 
{  alert(data);
}
else
{
// if valid, redirect
window.location("url");
}

});
```